# I am trying to create a bordered button animation in a way that but the button seems pressed if hovered but its getting shifted in unexpected manner

Tags: html, css, button, css-animations, css-transitions

I am using `translateY` to give the button a depth effect using CSS keyframes and then using that keyframe into `:hover` pseudo state with the help of the `animate` property. But, it's kind of shifting behind the `::after` element.

Any Possible solutions that could help me achieve the desired animation?

[image]

When the button is pressed or hovered (on Desktop) the white part should be pressing in a way that it gets dissolved with the white border.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.abstract-btn {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  background: #000000;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  position: relative;
  width: 195px;
  height: 46px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.abstract-btn::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 46px;
  width: 195px;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  z-index: -1
}

.abstract-btn::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: -5px;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 25px solid white;
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.abstract-btn:hover {
  animation: pressButton 1s ease both;
}

@keyframes pressButton {
  from {
    transform: translateZ(0px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateZ(3px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#" class="abstract-btn">
    Return Home
  </a>
</div>
```

Here, I am using the `::after` to create the white border and `::before` to add the triangle on the top right corner of the button.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's that style of button but I made one that looks like what you describe on my Codepen. Let me know if that's right.

https://codepen.io/ArthurCottey/pen/OJoMgZW

HTML:

```
<a class="top-left" target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/iamArthurCottey"></a>
```

CSS:

```
.top-left {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 48px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    background-color: #85a00d;
    color: black;
}

.top-left::after {
    content: 'Click here!';
    font-family: 'Advent Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    background-color: #d4f34a;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: -6px;
    left: -6px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: all 0.1s;
 }

.top-left:hover::after {
    top: -1.5px;
    left: -1px;
 }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with transitions on the `top` and `left` properties of both the `.abstract-btn` and `.abstract-btn::after`. The `.abstract-btn` having `display: flex;` was causing the problem of the `::after` showing in front. I changed it to `display: block;` then wrapped the link text in a span positioned in the center.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.abstract-btn {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  background: #000000;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  position: relative;
  width: 195px;
  height: 46px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.abstract-btn::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 46px;
  width: 195px;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.abstract-btn::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: -5px;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 25px solid white;
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.abstract-btn:hover {
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
}

.abstract-btn:hover::after {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.abstract-btn span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#" class="abstract-btn">
    <span>Return Home</span>
  </a>
</div>
```